# Looking for an easy way to align text

Tags: notepad++

I have a common problem that I'm looking for a solution to.
I have lines of similar text I'd like to somehow automatically insert text to align them vertically
such that:

```
x="foo" data="123" y=x
x="b  4" data="12 " y=x
x="baaar4" data="123aaa5" y=x
x="baaaa,4" data="123dddd5" y=x
```

becomes this

```
x="foo"     data="123"      y=x
x="b  4"    data="123 "     y=x
x="baaar4"  data="123aaa5"  y=x
x="baaaa,4" data="123dddd5" y=x
```

This is a text issue. The input comes from notepad. The output is going to notepad. This is not a formatting issue.

Comment: how? What I have is text in notepad. I could put the data into a database -- I suppose. But the number of "columns" would differ each time. What I want is to copy this text paste into a black box, hit a button, and be given the output. I think emacs had something like this.

Comment: It sounds like your tags are incorrect, you have the question tagged as html but are rejecting suggestions related to html.

Comment: Lets call it HTML development then

Comment: Found answer, but not enough "points" to answer it. -- There is a plugin for a program called  "Notepad++" called "Code Alignment". This accomplishes the task nicely.

Comment: how have you done it?

Comment: For Linux and platform-independent solution, check this Emiliano's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/61905015/5575723)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Notepad++ has a plugin that does this for you. It's called "[Code alignment](http://codealignment.com/)". It allows you to align text vertically based on characters of your choosing. You can install it via the Plugin Manager for notepad.

Below is a simple usage scenario. You start off with the following code, then you align by "equals" which is a built-in shortcut/command for the plugin.

[image: Initial Code Sample, without alignment]

After that, you end up with the following below:

[image: Code after equals alignment]

You can also take it a step further and use the "align by..." command which allows you to specify any arbitrary alignment string. In the example below, I chose the "#" character in order to align my comments next to one another. This could just as easily have been a longer string, and not one of length 1.

End result below:

[image: Final result after arbitrary code alignment string]

Comment: This WORKED beautifully and far better than TextFX which doesn't align with extra spaces. "Code alignment" was wonderful and exactly what I needed to indent some Java code based on STRINGS! Not just a character. A++++ to whoever wrote the plugin.

Comment: didn't work the first time, but after aligning by 'space' three times, it looked decent enough, thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, this addon didn't work for me when I tried to [align by comma](http://i.imgur.com/FSNuY5r.png)

Comment: Doesn't work for me - trying to align ascii table using pipe character only aligns groups of the rows, not all rows together.

Comment: @StevenM.Vascellaro - That looks aligned to me. This plugin won't detect multiple entries of the align char and split onto new-lines if there is more than one pair.

Comment: The link to codealignment.com doesn't work. Latest release of codealignment is here https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/releases/tag/v14.1  Unfortunately, it is not compatible with the current version of Notepad++

Comment: .. but installing Code Alignment from the Plugins Admin menu works.

Comment: Awesome plugin. Saved my day but it has some severe bugs so do not trust the results and verify your diffs. It can entirely mess your files.

Comment: I had text with headers. Some headers were spaced by tab and some with a single space. I found this plugin worked, by clicking between the headers (on just the first line) and selecting align by space. Once for each header.

Answer (score 29):

If you want to align by specific characters use Notepad++ extension TextFX.

Look at: TextFX > TextFX Edit > Line up multiple lines by (,)

There are also: Line up multiple lines by (=), and Line up multiple lines by (Clipboard Character)

Here is a link for helpful tips for programming.

http://techbrij.com/518/10-notepad-tips-tricks-fast-development

Comment: Every time I tried the Code alignment plugin it would freeze notepad++ and then wouldn't do anything upon resuming. TextFX works perfectly though.

Comment: This also worked for me, copying a TSQL Result set into notepad++ (which tab-separates). I was able to line up about 400 rows by 50 columns. However, TextFX wouldn't recognize tab as a clipboard character, and it wouldn't even accept "\t", but fortunately I was able to replace tabs with commas, line up by column, then change the commas back again (fortunately, there were no tabs or commas in my sql output!)

Comment: TextFX is a good plugin but aligning by `=` results in no leading space between the `=` and the characters preceding.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for, but there're two problem. First, it doesn't support double-byte characters content, like Chinese characters or Japanese characters. Second, the `character` used to line up lines doesn't support a very common separator: Tab (`\t`). Any alternatives or workaround?

Comment: Thanks. TextFX worked for me to align data rows delimited by commas. The Code Alignment package didn't work.

Comment: This works ugly (in-cell alignment can be padded wrong), but at least it *works* in contrast with "Code Alignment" NPP plugin presented in another answer, which doesn't align the whole table for me.

Comment: @Byzod One workaround is to find-and-replace all occurrences of the unsupported character with some control character that doesn't occur in your document.  For example, replacing all \t with \a (in "regular expression" mode) turns Tab into BEL, which is supported by the "Line up by clipboard character" function.  Afterwards, you can replace all BEL with, say, 4 spaces.

Comment: Works well with multiple columns, but I find it breaks on lines with ' in them, and unicode characters do not have their width counted correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Notepad++ TextFX is not longer supported and maintained. The Code alignment plugin only aligns the first occurence of the column aligning character.

I solved the problem using a free online service:
https://onlinetexttools.com/convert-text-to-nice-columns

Answer (score 3):

[ElasticTabstops](https://github.com/dail8859/ElasticTabstops/releases) is actually exactly doing the job I was looking for when you are working with tabs. 
Aligning without adding characters (spaces or tabs).

Answer (score 0):

You did not list a programming language so here is some C# that performs the requested operation:

```cs
int[] maxLengths = new int[100];
string[][] splitLines = new string[input.Length][];
for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++)
{
    splitLines[i] = input[i].Split(' ');
    for (int j = 0; j < splitLines[i].Length; j++)
    {
        maxLengths[j] = Math.Max(maxLengths[j], splitLines[i][j].Length);
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < splitLines.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < splitLines[i].Length; j++)
    {
        Console.Write(string.Format("0,-" + (maxLengths[j] + 1) + ":G}", splitLines[i][j]));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Note that 100 has to be greater than or equal to the number of segments per line. You can cause that number to not be fixed with a little work if you like.

Basically this algorithm splits each line based on spaces, then for each part calculates the maximum into a common array. Finally it loops through all these segmented parts and prints them out left-justified using spaces to the largest size (plus 1 to get the space between items).

Comment: this is an overkill. Text is in notepad++ (input) and OP wants the formatted text in notepad++ (output)

Comment: @anphu: The question does not include notepad++ anywhere in it. Notepad provides absolutely nothing like this so touching a different program is certainly necessary. I happened to write to console but you could equivalently write to the file you read from and get the same effect.

Comment: question is tagged under Notepad++

Comment: @anphu: It was tagged notepad++ erroneously by j08691, feel free to look at the comment where the original asker mentions they learned about "a program called notepad++". The answer was notepad++ and was accepted so the tags were retroactively changed. It is a 4 year old question so I am not going to fix the tags but my answer is not invalidated because the question was tagged to fit the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Python Script that can be used with Python Script Plugin in Notepad++: [nppPyAlignColumn](https://github.com/duzun/nppPyAlignColumn)

Comment: Hi, DUzun. Your script seems great. However, I have trouble install it. After I done everything, there is nothing in the menu "script", maybe it is incompatible with the newest version of notepad++??

Comment: If you don't have `doLocalConf.xml` file in NPP's folder, copy `AlignColumns.py` to  `%APPDATA%\Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts\` instead.

Answer (score 0):

***elastic tabstop plugin*** aligns messed up text in row and column

[image]

> install in notepad++