# Separate text into column by Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Does anybody know how to separate text into column in Notepad++?
My original text is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvVMS.png)

My text is separated by space and I need to put them in good order like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqvpy.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Looking for an easy way to align text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8808127/looking-for-an-easy-way-to-align-text)

Answer (score 1):

Hi There is a plugin in notepad++ that lets you do exactly what you want, it is called [CodeAlignment](http://codealignment.com/), To install in Notepad++ go to `Plugins > Plugin Manager> Show Plugin Manager`, then a window will apear, select `Code Alignment` to install.

Check the plugin if it is installed via `Plugin Manager > Show Plugin Manager > Intalled tab`

In your exaxmple, please try to use "`Align by space`"

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your answer, I tried your way but it's still not working in the way I want. My data still looks quite messy :(

Comment: @QuyNguyen I think the problem is the space, because you have 1 space and two space, I think you have to first align them in one space, then align them in two spaces, and so forth.